# How to create a model for messages in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, model

what's the best way in cakephp to get a list of private messages for a user considering my messages table is something like:

id: row id

left:sender id

right: receiver id

subject and text

with a find all i'll get the results with the user id but i want to display the username, ofcourse i could use a query with a join but probably there's a better way

thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Here's the plan:

1. You need to link your private
   messages table to the user, by using
   a `user_id` field.
2. Link the models
   via a `belongsTo` in the message
   private model.
3. Just perform a
   `Privatemessage->read()` from the
   current user, you'll get the data in
   a `privatemessage` array

Hope this helps,
Nicolas.